# Thoughts on scraping "sort" pages disallowed by robots.txt for search engine purposes?

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I'm building some spiders and am curious if there is any consensus on scraping pages that robots.txt disallows for what appears to be preventing these pages from showing up in search engines.

For example, I'm noticing some retail stores like https://www.barneys.com/robots.txt block certain sorted pages

```
Disallow: /*%7C*
Disallow: *product.maxSalePrice%7C1*
Disallow: /search*
```

https://www.barneys.com/category/sale/N-1d0527n?Ns=product.maxFinalPrice%7C1

Unless I'm missing another reason why they are blocking it (can't use up much more resources, can it?), and aside from automated anti-scraping measures, would anyone think I'd have a problem if I scraped one or two of these pages every 30 minutes? I'd imagine it would be better for both parties to do that rather than scrape every product page and sort the results myself. Would a search page for a specific term or two be any different, as these are typically disallowed as well?

I know it's going to depend on a site by site basis, but I'm curious to see what insight anyone might have.

Comment: If you really want to know what the site admins think about it, ask them. Send them an email :)

Answer (score 0):

If website has sitemap - you can receive product links by parsing sitemap.xml defined in robots.txt

```
Disallow: /checkout*
Disallow: *product.maxSalePrice%7C1*

Sitemap: https://www.barneys.com/sitemap_index.xml
```

You can use [`SitemapSpider`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.SitemapSpider) for it.

Comment: I'm less concerned with having to do some extra scraping and more so wondering if anyone would actually mind if I just scraped the one disallowed page instead of 30 product pages. That is helpful though, I haven't looked at that scrapy ability at all yet, thank you

Comment: For webserver processing single "search/" request with product filter can require more CPU and memory resources than processing requests for 30 product pages from sitemap.

Comment: Crawling this website using links from sitemap - is only way allowed by robots.txt